# How can I authorize a certain facebook account to delete comments in a facebook comment plugin?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

I have added facebook comments plugin to my site, and I want to control comments in the site. Is there a way to give certain facebook accounts the privilege to delete comments from the comment box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's fairly simple. All you need to do is to add an app id meta in your page head:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="<?= APP_ID; ?>" />
```

Then, every people listed as `Developper` in your app roles settings can moderate comments in comments boxes.

Some weeks ago, there was a `Moderator` roles available, but it's now deleted. Not sure what this particular role became; but `Developper` and `Admin` can moderate comments.